# Add 1 to both width and height while intitiallizing BufferedGraphicsContext

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msdn

I'm using `BufferedGraphics` to reduce flickering. But in [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), when initiallizing `BufferedGraphicsContext`, they added 1 to both width and height.

Code Part below:

```
private BufferedGraphicsContext context;
private BufferedGraphics grafx;

context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
context.MaximumBuffer = new Size(this.Width+1, this.Height+1); //here
grafx = context.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
```

I have tried to remove both of the `+1`, and it worked well.

So I'm wondering is there a case that only works normally with `+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaximumBuffer` throws an exception for `new Size(0, 0)`, so adding one is an easy way to avoid the case when `Width == 0` or `Height == 0`

Comment: but is there a chance that `Width` or `Height` being 0?

Comment: Oh! I got it! When we minimized the form, the resize part's form size will be (0, 0). If we didn't add 1 to the form's size, it will cause an error.